# React Native FormData not being sent to Django API

Tags: javascript, python, django, react-native, axios

I have created a simple Register page in Expo CLI but when I try to send the data to my Django Server it is not receiving the actual content like email password etc. I have tested this API with Postman its working fine there, any idea what might be causing this?

Here is the working example from Postmen
[Postman Working Api Calls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1HXOY.png)

Here is the Console Log Output [From the vscode terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xKa2.png)

And my Register.js Code

```
import {
  View,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  KeyboardAvoidingView,
  Image,
} from "react-native";
import React from "react";
import { Button, SafeAreaView } from "react-native";
import { TextInput, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native-gesture-handler";
import * as ImagePicker from "expo-image-picker";
import axios from "axios";
import { auth_URL } from "../config/env";

const Register = ({ navigation }) => {
  const [image, setImage] = React.useState(null);
  const [userData, setUserData] = React.useState({
    username: "",
    email: "",
    password: "",
    confirm_password: "",
  });

  const pickImage = async () => {
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
      allowsEditing: true,
      aspect: [4, 3],
      quality: 1,
    });

    console.log(result);

    if (!result.cancelled) {
      setImage(result.uri);
    }
  };

  var data = new FormData();
  data.append("username", userData.username);
  data.append("email", userData.email);
  data.append("password", userData.password);
  data.append("re_password", userData.confirm_password);
  data.append("image", {
    uri: image,
    type: "image/jpeg",
    name: "image.jpg",
  });

  const handleSubmit = () => {
    var config = {
      method: "post",
      url: `${auth_URL.AUTH_URI}/users/`,
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
      },
      data: data,
    };
    console.log(config);
    axios(config)
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error.response.data);
      });
  };
  return (
    <KeyboardAvoidingView>
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.header}>
        <Text style={styles.pageTitle}>Register</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => {
            navigation.navigate("Login");
          }}
        >
          <Text style={styles.pageSubtitle}>Go Back</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </SafeAreaView>
      <View style={styles.formContainer}>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.imageHolder} onPress={pickImage}>
          {image ? (
            <Image source={{ uri: image }} style={styles.profileImage} />
          ) : (
            <Image
              source={require("../assets/profile_placeholder.png")}
              style={styles.profileImage}
            />
          )}

          <Text style={styles.imageText}>Upload Profile Image or Gif</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <View style={styles.InputContainer}>
          <TextInput
            style={styles.input}
            placeholder="Username"
            autoCapitalize="none"
            placeholderTextColor="white"
            value={userData.username}
            onChangeText={(text) =>
              setUserData({ ...userData, username: text })
            }
          />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.InputContainer}>
          <TextInput
            style={styles.input}
            placeholder="Email"
            autoCapitalize="none"
            keyboardType="email-address"
            placeholderTextColor="white"
            value={userData.email}
            onChangeText={(text) => setUserData({ ...userData, email: text })}
          />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.InputContainer}>
          <TextInput
            style={styles.input}
            placeholder="Password"
            autoCapitalize="none"
            placeholderTextColor="white"
            secureTextEntry={true}
            value={userData.password}
            onChangeText={(text) =>
              setUserData({ ...userData, password: text })
            }
          />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.InputContainer}>
          <TextInput
            style={styles.input}
            placeholder="Confirm Password"
            autoCapitalize="none"
            placeholderTextColor="white"
            secureTextEntry={true}
            value={userData.confirm_password}
            onChangeText={(text) =>
              setUserData({ ...userData, confirm_password: text })
            }
          />
        </View>
      </View>
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonContainer} onPress={handleSubmit}>
        <Text style={styles.button}>Sign Up</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </KeyboardAvoidingView>
  );
};

export default Register;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  header: {
    marginTop: 50,
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "space-between",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  pageTitle: {
    alignContent: "center",
    fontSize: 30,
    fontWeight: "bold",
    margin: 20,
    color: "white",
  },
  pageSubtitle: {
    alignContent: "center",
    fontSize: 14,
    fontWeight: "bold",
    margin: 20,
    color: "white",
  },
  imageHolder: {
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "column",
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    marginBottom: 20,
  },
  profileImage: {
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    borderRadius: 50,
    marginLeft: 30,
    marginRight: 30,
    marginBottom: 20,
  },
  imageText: {
    color: "white",
    fontSize: 14,
    marginLeft: 30,
    marginRight: 30,
    textAlign: "center",
  },
  formContainer: {
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "column",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
  InputContainer: {
    marginLeft: 30,
    marginRight: 30,
    marginTop: 10,
    padding: 16,
    backgroundColor: "#343a40",
    borderRadius: 10,
  },
  input: {
    fontWeight: "400",
    fontSize: 14,
    color: "#fff",
  },
  buttonContainer: {
    marginLeft: 30,
    marginRight: 30,
    marginTop: 16,
    padding: 16,
    backgroundColor: "#0d1321",
    borderRadius: 10,
    borderColor: "white",
    borderWidth: 2,
  },
  button: {
    fontWeight: "600",
    fontSize: 16,
    color: "white",
    textAlign: "center",
  },
});
```

Comment: Are you getting data or error in Promise of Axios API?

Comment: Yeah Its saying that username, email, password fields are required. But I have already passed this in the FormData.